# how to read .txt file and merge with .xlsx

Tags: python, pandas

i've big myfile.txt (52,375 kb, ln 86213, 18), as below

```
E.g

myfile.txt

  "Name"     "ID"   "School"            .                 .
  "steven"  "1212"  "harvard"          .                 .
  "michael" "9898"  "stanford"         .                 . 
     .      .      .
     .      .      .



In [1]
df1 = pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", sep = "\t", lineterminator = "\n")

Out [1]
           Name     ID  School            .                 .
  steven  1212  harvard          .                 .
  michael 9898  stanford         .                 . 
     .      .      .
     .      .      .
```

but when i want to merge with database.xlsx, it doest work. it only shows about the title of data frame after merge

```
In [2]: df2 = pd.read_excel('Data Base Currency.xlsx')

Out [2]:
ID       status
1212     mechanical engineering
9898     electrical engineering

In [3]: df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = "ID", how = "inner")

**and then my merge statement doesn't work**
Out [3]:
Name     ID  School   status
```

my expected

```
  Name     ID                     School            .                 .
  steven  mechanical engineering  harvard          .                 .
  michael Electrical engineering  stanford         .                 . 
     .      .      .
     .      .      .
```

Comment: It looks like the labels in `df1` might be off by one.  Is `df1["ID"]` what you expect?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh my expect the format of df1 will same with my row data, but when i code `pd.read_csv("myfile.txt", sep = "\t", lineterminator = "\n")` the name will move

Comment: Is there a `\t` in front of the first label?  Try `with open('myfile.txt') as f: print(repr(next(f)))` to check.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh yes sir,theris a `\t` in back of the label, e.g `'"NAME"\t"ID"\t"`

Comment: is the datatype same for ID in both the df's ?

Comment: @asimo ID in df1 = object, ID in df2 = object

Comment: have you tried outer join or left join and see if there is any output ?

Comment: @asimo thanks for your attention, i used merge, and ther's output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you have columns with different data types. 
Try to run this and tell what heppens:

```
df1["ID"] = df1["ID"].astype(int)
df2["ID"] = df2["ID"].astype(int)
df3 = pd.merge(df1,df2, on = "ID", how = "inner")
```

Comment: on my dataframe i've receive warning: Columns (5,6,8,10,11) have mixed types. the question is number of column start from 0 or 1?

Comment: use df.iloc[:,[your_column_number(s) ]] to select them by order

Comment: ```` DtypeWarning: Columns (5,6,8,10,11) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.
  interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result) ```` how to solve this?

Comment: Generally,  this means that you have string and digit in the column f.e. [2, 3, '4']
So you should convert this to the same type. This could be done while and after loading.